# Canvas - Keeping aspect ratio while also keeping pixel amount

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas like so:
[image: The canvas with a banana duck and some cheese]
But when resizing the window and redrawing, you can get anything in between.
[image: The duck with only a few cheeses]

I keep the aspect ratio with this code:

```js
function setCanvasSize(){
    ctx.canvas.width = (window.innerWidth)*0.8;
    ctx.canvas.height= (window.innerWidth)*0.5;
}
setCanvasSize()
$(window).resize(function(){
    setCanvasSize()
})
```

and that keeps it nice and clean, the same-looking size, but how many pixels are in there changes, so when my program draws, it's always in a different spot, although the aspect is the same, so it looks really weird.

Any way that I can somehow tweak how I draw things, or a way to keep how many pixels there are?

Edit: code snippet to reproduce

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('game').getContext("2d");

$('#game').css('width', '100%');
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#game').height($('#game').width() / 2.031);
 });
 
 const imageAt=((href,x,y,sizex,sizey)=>{
      var img = new Image();
      img.addEventListener('load', function() {
          ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, sizex, sizey);
      }, false);
      img.src = href
  })
imageAt('https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/bZedgr0gq7RQBBnVYVc-Nmzdr-5vEUg4Dj8nTrMb7yA.png',0,0,50,50)
```

```css
#game{
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    border:5px solid green;
    padding:0;
}

#vertical-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  padding:0;
}

body{
  background-color: black;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tiled Canvas Engine Test 1</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.75">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="engine.js"></script>
        <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="vertical-center">
            <canvas id="game"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may need to also update the canvas element's style width and height if you had set that previously such as via CSS. `ctx.canvas.style.width`

Comment: @Ouroborus no style concerning its width or height is ever added outside the `setCanvasSize` function.

Answer (score 1):

In order to render properly the `canvas` element needs to have its `width` and `height` attributes set explicitly. This will define the viewport into which graphics will be draw. The style attributes for `width` and `height` which is what jQuery sets via the `width()` and `height()` functions will only stretch the viewport to fit. (Note: for high DPI displays, i.e. Retina, you will want to double the dimensions when specifying the attributes).

The critical change is this:

```
  // Updates the actual width and height attributes
  canvas.width = $('#game').width() * window.devicePixelRatio;
  canvas.height = $('#game').height() * window.devicePixelRatio;
```

The snippet below also handles clearing the canvas, redrawing the image, and saving the Image once loaded:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('game').getContext("2d");

$('#game').css('width', '100%');
$(document).ready(handleResize);
$(window).resize(handleResize);

function handleResize() {
  // sets the style.height and style.width for the canvas
  $('#game').height($('#game').width() / 2.031);
  let canvas = $('#game').get(0);

  // Updates the actual width and height attributes
  canvas.width = $('#game').width() * window.devicePixelRatio;
  canvas.height = $('#game').height() * window.devicePixelRatio;

  // redraw
  if (img) {
    redraw();
  }
}

var img;
const imageAt = ((href, x, y, sizex, sizey) => {
  img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, sizex, sizey);
  }, false);
  img.src = href
})
imageAt('https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/bZedgr0gq7RQBBnVYVc-Nmzdr-5vEUg4Dj8nTrMb7yA.png', 0, 0, 50 * window.devicePixelRatio, 50 * window.devicePixelRatio)

function redraw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50 * window.devicePixelRatio, 50 * window.devicePixelRatio);
}
```

```css
#game {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 0;
}

#vertical-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tiled Canvas Engine Test 1</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.75">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="engine.js"></script>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="vertical-center">
    <canvas id="game"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. Discussed this in replit discord: https://discord.com/channels/437048931827056642/437062563620978708/941862366101004318

Comment: I updated the snippet to account for high DPI displays